# Question on Conditional Expectation and Removing Conditionals

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $D$ and $Z$ be two random variables, where $D$ is binary. Let $P(Z) = \mathbb{P}(D=1|Z)$.

\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[D=1 | P(Z) = u] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}[D=1 | Z, P(Z) = u] | P(Z)=u]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}[D=1 | Z] | P(Z)=u]\\
&= \mathbb{E}[P(Z) | P(Z)=u]\\
&= u
\end{split}

I understand that the first equality follows from law of iterated expectations. My question is that in this proof, in the second equality, why are we able to remove the inner conditional of $P(Z)=u$?

Is the reason that $P(Z)$ is a function of $Z$ and we can drop any expression that involves functions that take only $Z$ as argument, when $Z$ is included in the conditional?

Comment: Indeed, in full generality, $$E(X\mid Y,g(Y))=E(X\mid Y)$$ because $$\sigma(g(Y))\subseteq\sigma(Y)$$ hence $$\sigma(Y,g(Y))=\sigma(Y)$$

Comment: @Did I guess my confusion is coming from the fact that the conditional is not really "|Z ,P(Z)" but rather "|Z , P(Z)=u". The full generality stuff you stated, is it essentially saying that all events related to functions of Z (like the equality) are events of Z and so we can just consider Z?

Comment: More or less that, yes, but rather the fact that every event $$[(Y,g(Y))\in B]$$ is also some event $$[Y\in C]$$